# Regression Notation - does the distribution of $y_i$ refer to the distribution of $(Y|X)$?

Tags: regression, normality-assumption, notation

The title question is the main focus of what I am trying to understand, but the reasoning behind my asking is more nuanced.

I have recently made transition from learning about basic forms of regression to studying generalized linear models. In doing so, I've realized some gaps in my understanding fundamentals of assumption analysis.

Namely, most learning resources emphasize the assumption that $y_i$ be normally distributed in order to perform a linear regression.

This is contrary to my understanding, which is that $y_i$ is a random variable that simply represents a single observation in the sample. Its distribution should mirror that of the entire population, which we do not know, but estimate with the sample distribution.

Here is my confusion: In regression, we generally do not care about the distribution of our dependent variable itself, we only care that the residuals of our estimates are normally distributed.

Therefore, to make the assertion that $y_i$ must be normally distributed, the only way this would make sense is if $y_i$ = $(Y|X)$. I have not seen explicit clarification of this, however.

Any insight would be much appreciated, thanks so much!

Comment: You are right, it is only the distribution of Y conditional on the explanatory variables that matters. Terminology is often not sharp in this regards

Comment: I am afraid it is more than poor terminology. It is a lack of understanding among many.

Comment: It is worth noting that the assumption is also that the errors are conditionally normally distributed. Even if the errors are truly marginally normally distributed, it is possible that the response is conditionally non-normal. This issue is important. For example, in cases with highly discrete Y,  naive users sometimes look at a normal q-q plot of the residuals and conclude "no violation of normality."

Comment: Yes, the usual assumption is that $y$ ~  $N(X\beta, \sigma^2 I)$ where $N(...)$ is the multivariate normal distribution with the given vector mean and variance covariance matrix. $y$ is a random vector representing the dependent variable, $X$ is a fixed known matrix and $\beta$ is a fixed but unknown vector representing the coefficients .  $\sigma$ is a scalar which is fixed but unknown and $I$ is the identity matrix.

Answer (score 0):

One way to further explore this question is to consider a data generation mechanism such as $$X\sim N(0,1), Y|X \sim N(\beta X,\sigma^2).$$  What does this imply about the marginal distribution of $Y\sim N(?,?).$  To get this, one can use for example $$E(Y)=E(E(Y|X)).$$

As you said, with regression analysis we typically model $Y|X.$